# application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

Here is my full "AppDelegate.swift" file:

```
import UIKit

import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("NOT SHOWING MY KEY",
            clientKey: "NOT SHOWING MY KEY2")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var pushPayload = false
            if let options = launchOptions {
                pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
                //PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
            }
        }
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        //installation.saveInBackground()
        installation.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            println("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            println("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

I have set up everthing from here:
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/swift/existing

When i have xCode opened, and testing my app using cable to iphone, and When i press "Try" from site i get error:

> Warning: Application delegate received call to
>   -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your `AppDelegate.swift` a bit. This should be all you need to register and use push notifications. I also added a function at the end to clear the badge counter when the user opens the app:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("NOT SHOWING MY KEY",
            clientKey: "NOT SHOWING MY KEY2")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
            UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
            UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            println("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            println("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }

    // ADDED FUNCTION:
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

        //Reset badge counter to zero
        var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        if(currentInstallation.badge != 0){
            currentInstallation.badge = 0
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do what the error message suggests : Call the completion handler

From the documentation

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the
>   block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your
>   app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the
>   notification and call the specified completion handler block. In
>   practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done
>   processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power
>   usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. Apps that
>   use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications
>   may not always be woken up early to process future notifications.

so, for example call

```
completionHandler(.NewData)
```